# Where to put documentation relating to multiple git repos

Tags: git, github

I have a project which includes 4 forked repos.  I have kept these separate as they do quite different things, but work together across the project.

The project requires all the repos and I want to keep all the documentation in one place so people have one single point for modification and configuration notes especially those config options which affect more than one repo (such as initialising the forked libraries in the core application.

So where is best practice to put the single point of documentation? Should we put it on one project and just link to it from the others or is there some 'git' way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

The technical documentation is itself subject to versioning and source control. I recommend making a separate repository for it. It can later be included as a submodule to each of the 4 projects.

Here's an example of such documentation repo by Jetbrains: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-docs

Also, if you plan to use GitHub wiki pages - they are stored in a hidden repository. One can clone it and do all other git things with it.